# using href when creating wordpress plugin calls empty page instead of php file

Tags: plugins, php

I'm currently developing my first wordpress plugin. It's a plugin which manages all the members and other data from a club. I read the members from a MySql database which works fine. What I now want is to set a link to each member name, which will call the details of the member when the user clicked.

I have three php files for now:

1st: menu.php: This just creates a menu item in the backend

2nd: admin.php: This contains the MySql connection and the loop to get all the members. This also contains the link for each member.

3rd: member.php: This file should be the details page to each member (depending on what member the user selected).

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    $path = "member.php?memberid=" . $row[0];
    $url = admin_url($path);
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td><td><a href='{$url}'>" . $row[1] . "</a></td></tr>";
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to call member.php from admin.php and pass the member's ID using the URL.

My problem now is that when I click on a link, it just call an empty (white) page, without any wordpress design. For testing, I just echoed some random text, but this is not displayed, neither.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible in this way? Or how can I achieve this?

I don't know if it helps you helping me, but here you can see the code from menu.php:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'AddMenuItem');

function AddMenuItem()
{
    add_menu_page('Admin Plugin', 'Admin Plugin', 'add_users', 'admin-plugin\admin.php', '',  '', 100);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `mysql` extension and it's functions, that extension is deprecated and was removed in newer versions of PHP. Consider using `mysqli` or `PDO` for generic PHP database work, or use `WPDB` when in a WordPress environment. Also, you're missing escaping on the output of `$row`, making you vulnerable to injection attacks, and consider avoiding magic quotes when outputing the `$url` variable, I would recommend: `".esc_url( $url )."`

Comment: Also, a white page of death usually indicates an error occurred, and the message was written to the PHP error log. Please review the debugging documentation to find what the actual error is, from there it may be a trivial fix ( e.g. a missing bracket ), we will need to know what the message is in order to help. Where is `member.php` coming from?

Comment: @TomJNowell Okay, thank you, I'll change it to `mysqli`. And also thanks for the hint with the url. I'll keep that in mind as well. I cannot find any error in the error log. Am I reading the right one? `/apache/logs/error.log`?

Comment: `member.php` is in the same folder as `menu.php` and `admin.php`. It should contain the details of the called member.

Comment: If you're trying to implement a new admin page, adding a file under `wp-admin` is quite a difficult and counterproductive approach. You can do it via plugins and themes using the APIs. Also that's the Apache error log, you'll need the PHP error log, refer to your php.ini for its location ( or if logging is turned on ). Chances are you haven't bootstrapped and loaded the WordPress environment and its failing at the first function call you make

Comment: Well, in the location of my `php.ini` file is a subfolder called `logs`. In this folder there is a logfile called `php_error_log`. In this file there are all the errors I had before, but the last one is not referring to my plugin.

Comment: @TomJNowell I added my plugin to `\wp-content\plugins\admin-plugin`. It's not located in `wp-admin` folder.

Comment: You still need to load WordPress in `member.php`, but I wouldn't take this approach, as even when the plugin is deactivated, that file can still be accessed, and will still execute. Instead use the APIs you used earlier to generate that page

Comment: @TomJNowell How do you mean that "use the APIs you used earlier to generate that page"? I just have the `menu.php` file which creates the backend menu item and the `admin.php` file to read the database. What should I put in `href` tag? Or what should I use instead if links?

Comment: @TomJNowell Well I now managed it that the page isn't blank anymore (I had a wrong linkage). But the whole wordpress design is not there, it's just a blank page with my test code which echoes a variable. Why is the link leaving wordpress? And how can I keep it inside of the wordpress environment?

Comment: You used `add_menu_page` to create a menu page, you can use that API to create your members page too

Comment: @TomJNowell Okay, thank you. I now managed that the wordpress environment is loaded using `add_submenu_page(null, '', '', 'add_users', 'admin-plugin\member.php', '');` in `menu.php`. This works now when I call `member.php` from `admin.php`. But if I add some parameters to the URL like e.g. `member.php?memberid=2` then it doesn't work anymore. I get this error: `you do not have sufficient permissions to access this page`. Can you please help me again?

Comment: You have it the wrong way round, WordPress should load your admin pages code, you should never send the browser directly to a file inside your plugin

Comment: @TomJNowell But how can I link to the `member.php` page when not directly call it in `href` tag?

Comment: You don't, the browser never visits `member.php`, look at the other page you added using `add_menu_page`, the browser isn't pointed at the file you called that function in, it's at `options-general.php?page=`.. etc Your browser should never be sent directly to a PHP file in a plugin or theme as it's a security issue, and brings other practical issues with it

Comment: @TomJNowell Okay, but how can I visit the details of a member when not calling the file in a link?

Comment: by specifying in a GET parameter the ID of the member

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes that is clear to me but what is unclear is, I add the whole details stuff to `member.php`. And if I then click on a link in `admin.php`, I have to display the `member.php` file. I stuck on this...

Comment: add a new admin page, dedicated to showing the member, note down the URL of that new admin page, then link to that page, and add to the end `&member=xx`. If you really want your pages contents to be in a file called `member.php`, do `include( "member.php");`. As a sidenote, you could do away with the need for a new page entirely by simply testing if a `member` GET variable is set and showing something different instead